# Prove the following equation has a unique solution: $x^{101} + x^{99} + 5x + 2 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following equation has a unique solution:
$x^{101} + x^{99} + 5x + 2 = 0$

(Use continuity for existence and Rolle's Theorem for uniqueness)

I have no idea where to start and how to prove.

Answer (score 2):

To use continuity, you should find some points $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a)<0$ and 
$f(b)>0$, where $$f(x)=x^{101}+x^{99}+5x+2.$$ This will prove that there must be some $c$, between $a$ and $b$, such that $f(c)=0$. (This is actually the Intermediate Value Theorem, a consequence of continuity.)

From here: Roll's theorem tells us that if you have two points $c$ and $d$ such that $f(c)=f(d)$, then there is a point $p$ between $c$ and $d$ such that $f'(p)=0$.  You can compute $f'$ quite easily; what about it tells us that it is impossible for it to ever satisfy $f'(x)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^{101}+x^{99}+5x+2$. Then $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, so by the Intermediate Value Theorem exists at least one solution to $f(x)=0$.

If there were at least two solutions $a\neq b$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then by Roll's theorem this would imply $\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$, but $f'(x)=101x^{100}+99x^{98}+5>0,\, \forall x\in\Bbb R$.